# Punctuation when using a list of adjective pairs set apart by "yet"

Tags: punctuation, adjectives, lists

I'm proofreading something, and came across this sentence:

> We believe the strength of our design is in our ability to be dynamic yet focused, clean yet inviting and organized yet exploratory.

It kind of feels like it needs some more punctuation to be more readable, but the only idea I had was to add semi-colons, which made it feel kind of choppy:

> We believe the strength of our design is in our ability to be dynamic, yet focused; clean, yet inviting; and organized, yet exploratory.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why the close votes? Is this frivolous?

Comment: I don't think semicolons are that necessary here, the comma should do. Like @Andrew Leach said, just drop the *and*, replacing with a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punctuation police are going to jump on me for this, but this seems to me like a case for a comma before the "and".  It would add readability, even though it would stray a little from the prescriptivists' rule book.

Comment: I love (and use) the Oxford comma! And this is a case when it would improve the meaning.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the Oxford comma as well. :)

Answer (score 4):

I like the bullet-point directness of the second example, but I would drop the *and*. Asyndeton has much to recommend itself in punchy lists.

> We believe the strength of our design is in our ability to be dynamic, yet focused; clean, yet inviting; organized, yet exploratory.

Comment: +1 Right about the *and*. Obviously, OP's intent was a 'punchy' effect. However, the semicolons seem too glaring. Commas should do, I think.

Comment: Actually not feeling the punchiness so much, that was partly my issue with the semi colons. Thanks for your suggestion, though.